# add legend to a scatterplot with automatic assignment in R

Tags: r

I'm working withThe AndersonIrisData set.How do i Make a scatter plot With A legend That automatically Corresponds To The filled in Values?

i have

```
plot(Petal.Length,col=Species)
legend(x="bottomright",legend = c('setosa','versicolor','virginica'))
```

it makes an incomplete legend

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
legend(x="bottomright",legend = c('setosa','versicolor','virginica'), 
  col = unique(iris$Species), lty = 1)
```

You need to specify both `col` and `lty` for it to work. Note that colors will be assigned in the order of `unique(iris$Species)` so if you were to re-sort `iris` a different way, your colors may not match.

[image]

You can also do this with `ggplot2` which provides a more friendly syntax for plotting, along with automatically generating legends:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID,Petal.Length, color = Species)) + geom_point()
```

[image]